# Ansible : Replace variable with another variable

Tags: linux, replace, ansible

I have a strange behavior while trying to replace a string with another string.
Both strings are under variable. The first one is inside a list in the same .yml
The second one is declared on another file.
I test two differents replace :

```
- name: log data 1 with the value in raw
        debug:
          msg: "{{item.stdout | replace('-1.0.1','')}}"
        loop: "{{ all_stations.results }}"

- name: log data 2 with the value inside a variable
        debug:
          msg: "{{item.stdout | replace('-{{ ctrl_router_version }}','')}}"
        loop: "{{ all_stations.results }}"
```

with ctrl_router_version : 1.0.1 in another file

with item.stdout = "abcd-efgh-1.0.1"

The results :

In the first one we have :

> "msg": "abcd-efgh"

And in the second one we have :

> "msg": "abcd-efgh-1.0.1"

I would like to know how is that possible that the 2 results are differents, how the second replace is not working with the value inside a variable ?

Also, I m looking for a solution to the second one.

Thank you !

I tried playing with the quotes but with no result

Answer (score 1):

Yes because the replace filter in `Jinja2` does not support variable substitution,you can use the `regex_replace` filter instead, which does support variable substitution! as you see I concatenate the `-` character and the value of `ctrl_router_version` using the `~` operator, and then use the `regex_replace` filter to perform the replacement.

```
name: log data 2 with the value inside a variable
debug:
  msg: "{{ item.stdout | regex_replace('-' ~ ctrl_router_version, '') }}"
loop: "{{ all_stations.results }}"
```

Comment: Ah that's why. It's interesting. It's working ! Thank you very much :)

Comment: `"... the replace filter in Jinja2 does not support variable substitution ..."` ?!

Answer (score 1):

Fix the syntax

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.stdout|replace(ctrl_router_version , '') }}"
      loop:
        - stdout: abcd-efgh-1.0.1
```

Then, both expressions give you the same result

```yaml
  msg: abcd-efgh
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    ctrl_router_version: -1.0.1

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.stdout|replace('-1.0.1', '') }}"
      loop:
        - stdout: abcd-efgh-1.0.1

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.stdout|replace(ctrl_router_version , '') }}"
      loop:
        - stdout: abcd-efgh-1.0.1
```